# Get last value per year counting from the last date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What's the best way in Pandas to resample/group/etc by year, but instead of going by calendar years, calculate full years starting with the last date in the data?

**Example data set**

```
pd.DataFrame({
  'MyDate': ['2017-02-01', '2017-07-05', '2017-08-26', '2017-09-03', '2018-02-04', 
             '2018-08-03', '2018-08-10', '2018-12-03', '2019-07-13', '2019-08-15'],
  'MyValue': [100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10]
})
```

```
    MyDate  MyValue
0   2017-02-01  100
1   2017-07-05  90
2   2017-08-26  80
3   2017-09-03  70
4   2018-02-04  60
5   2018-08-03  50
6   2018-08-10  40
7   2018-12-03  30
8   2019-07-13  20
9   2019-08-15  10
```

**Example result**

Last date is 2019-08-15, so I'd like to group by the last full year 2018-08-16 - 2019-08-15, the 2017-08-17 - 2018-08-15, etc.

Here getting the last result per such year:

```
MyDate  MyValue
0   2017-07-05  90
1   2018-08-10  40
2   2019-08-15  10
```

Comment: For the expected result, for the year 2017 are you sure you pasted the good row ? Don't you want `2017-09-03  70` instead ?

Comment: @BenoitDrogou No, as 2017-09-03 (September 3rd) is is past the cut-off date of August 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `pd.cut`, specifying the bins with `pd.offsets.DateOffset` to get calendar year separation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['MyDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MyDate'])

N = int(np.ceil((df.MyDate.max()-df.MyDate.min())/np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')))+1
bins = [df.MyDate.max()-pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=y) for y in range(N)][::-1]

df.groupby(pd.cut(df.MyDate, bins)).last()

#                             MyDate  MyValue
#MyDate                                      
#(2016-08-15, 2017-08-15] 2017-07-05       90
#(2017-08-15, 2018-08-15] 2018-08-10       40
#(2018-08-15, 2019-08-15] 2019-08-15       10
```

Comment: Accepted for beautiful simplicity and the added bonus of the output range

Answer (score 3):

You can subtract last value and create years groups and pass to `groupby` with [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html):

```
df['MyDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MyDate'])

s = (df['MyDate'].sub(df['MyDate'].iat[-1]).dt.days / 365.25).astype(int)
df = df.groupby(s).last().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      MyDate  MyValue
0 2017-07-05       90
1 2018-08-10       40
2 2019-08-15       10
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, but the 365.25 is somehow causing me pain

Answer (score 3):

You first need to parse your dates to real date objects, like:

```
df['MyDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MyDate'])
```

Next we can perform a group by with a [**`relativedelta`**](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) from the [**`python-dateutil`** package](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/):

```
>>> from operator import attrgetter
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> df.groupby(df['MyDate'].apply(relativedelta, dt2=df['MyDate'].max()).apply(attrgetter('years'))).last()
           MyDate  MyValue
MyDate                    
-2     2017-07-05       90
-1     2018-08-10       40
 0     2019-08-15       10
```

Comment: This answer has the slowest performance by far (1 second vs 40 ms of the other answers locally for me), but upvoted for interesting use of relativedelta and attrgetter!

Comment: @AlexFriedman: Well the answer aims to define a "year" correctly :). Unfortunately the calendar is not very easy, since not every year has the same number of years. But I agree that it is not extremely fast.

Comment: The DateOffset used by ALollz in their answer does work fast, probably because it's native in pandas.